# Replace NULL value and blank space in DATETIME column with string as "Not Available"?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SSIS project I need to replace null value of datetime column with string "Not Available".I tried with this query select coalesce(convert( varchar(30), DateOfBirth, 121 ), 'Not Available') as [DateOFBIRTH]
it's replacing,but when doing SCD transform for ETL, mapping error coming as in destination the DateOfBirth column is having datatype DATETIME and while selecting from source converting to varchar(30)

Comment: why you do this in ssis and don't want to do in ssas?

Comment: Set destination column to nullabe datetime and insert null to destination instead of 'NotAvailable', after tranfer data to destination replace the null value with 'NotAvailable'

Comment: That means you are telling after ETL process I have to replace he null value. Is there any solution to replace null value during ETL process .Saeed Esmaeelinejad

Comment: Hi ali azizan,I am using SSIS tool for ETL process and then I will create cube using SSAS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try that?

```
isnull(DateOfBirth, 'Not Available') as [DateOFBIRTH]
```

If you want 'Not Available' as value, you have to set destination field DateOFBIRTH as varchar.

Comment: Error:Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Answer (score 0):

As indicated, in order to be able to load "Not Available" into the table itself, it needs to be a varchar or nvarchar type (*not* a DateTime type). Once you have that, have two separate steps: load data into your table in one step and then write an Execute SQL Task to execute immediately after and update it:

```
UPDATE [yourTableName]
SET DateOfBirth = 'Not Available'
WHERE DateOfBirth is null
```